# Which javascript library better suited for dynamic realtime widgets/dashboard?

Tags: python, backbone.js, socket.io, dashboard

I will build a dashboard for internal use in html5. I'm struggling in what library use for the client-side of refresh of realtime/dynamic widgets (graphs, status, etc) like this screenshoot:

[image: Sample idea]

The idea is have a backend server that push with Socket.IO the data to the client(s). In the dashboard, several widgets will be update potentially each few seconds. The widgets will be added/deleted by the user. So, the app is contained in a single page.

I don't have experience in use this kind of libraries, mainly backend code with python/c#. I have heard about http://backbonejs.org/ but wonder which library fit best to my use case:

I wish to have a way to separate the render from the data sources, ie: The data is "CPU usage" and is rendered AT THE SAME TIME by two widgets: A line chart and a speedometer.

P.D: This is not the actual design of my dashboard, is only for show the *kind* of user interface similar to what I could develop (I don't have yet the gui). The original design belong to http://dribbble.com/shots/780188-Morning

Comment: Take a look at AngularJS and its very very sweet integration with Socket.IO and check my upcoming presentation at PyCon.ca which will do exactly that: build a realtime analytics dashboard with gevent-socketio and AngularJS

Comment: Is this talk http://pycon.ca/talk/54? Will be available later in video/pdf? Look like the one thing I'm looking!

Comment: Any help in how reopen the question? Or where ask it again?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with all the available JavaScript frameworks, but I know backbone will certainly meet your requirements. In reality, any of the MV* frameworks should allow you to update multiple views synchronously to reflect changes to a single model.

You may find [this article](http://blog.andyet.com/2011/feb/15/re-using-backbonejs-models-on-the-server-with-node/) on sharing models between client and (node) server a compelling argument in favour of backbone.

If you think the ability to directly bind your HTML elements to model data will be useful, [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/introduction.html) might be worth considering also.

Comment: Certainly the ability to bind and update HTML based in the model data is key here...